# HP ProBook 6450b not booting after memory upgrade

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory

I recently tried to upgrade my [ProBook 6450b](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c03471180/c03471180.pdf) from 4GB to 8GB of memory (the listed maximum).

When installing the new pair I purchased (which is within spec for the laptop per the manual (referenced above)), the BIOS can see 8192MB, but Windows will not boot (7 x64 Pro).

I also cannot run the built-in memory test.

For the time being, I have reverted to the 4GB that was in the machine, but this is not ideal, and I am hoping someone here can assist.

Comment: Why are you unable to run the built-in memory test?  You need to verify the memory is good use your program of choice.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have no idea. The BIOS memory test will not run.

Comment: That would indicate a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad memory can cause this - to find out which stick is bad remove one of them and boot, if it doesn't boot remove other one and install the first stick then boot again.

Comment: the BIOS can see both; with just one, it also sees 4GB (in either slot). OS still won't come up.

Comment: Ok, i have seen this before where you can post but when you try to boot the OS it freezes / crashes. Have you tried removing one stick and booting?

Comment: yes, see my previous comment :)

Comment: does it boot with only one stick? you said "it also sees 4GB (in either slot). OS still won't come up" sorry for my miss understanding :P

Comment: no - the BIOS still sees the memory. But it won't boot into the OS. Doesn't matter which slot has the memory (1 or 2). But with the factory-supplied RAM it's all good. It's Mushkin, if the brand matters.

Comment: Ok but either sticks will boot with it? is there XMP settings in your bios for "extreme memory" ? its very rare that both sticks would be bad.

Comment: the OS will not boot with the new memory in any configuration I have yet tried.

Comment: Ok, is your memory overclocked? i had this problem and when i enabled XMP (extreme memory profile) it started working.

Comment: it's stock - though I can look for XMP when i next reboot